# rrule to get the 2nd Monday, Wednesday and Friday of the month, for every month

Tags: fullcalendar, rrule

I am trying to create a rrule for my fullcalendar event, that occur on the 2nd Monday, Wednesday and Friday of the month for every month.

Here is the rrule I have tried

RRULE:FREQ=MONTHLY;COUNT=10;INTERVAL=1;WKST=SU;BYDAY=MO,WE,FR;BYSETPOS=2

```
events: [{
          title: 'rrule event',
          rrule: {
           freq: RRule.MONTHLY,
               count: 10,
               interval: 1,
               wkst: RRule.SU,
               byweekday: [RRule.MO, RRule.WE, RRule.FR],
               bysetpos: [2]
            },
            duration: '02:00',
        rendering: 'inverse-background'
         }
        ],
```

This is what I get

```
1   Fri,    03  May 2019    12:33:53    GMT
2   Wed,    05  Jun 2019    12:33:53    GMT
3   Wed,    03  Jul 2019    12:33:53    GMT
4   Mon,    05  Aug 2019    12:33:53    GMT
5   Wed,    04  Sep 2019    12:33:53    GMT
6   Fri,    04  Oct 2019    12:33:53    GMT
7   Mon,    04  Nov 2019    12:33:53    GMT
8   Wed,    04  Dec 2019    12:33:53    GMT
9   Fri,    03  Jan 2020    12:33:53    GMT
10  Wed,    05  Feb 2020    12:33:53    GMT
```

What is expected is

```
1    Mon,  08   Apr   2019
2    Wed,  10   Apr   2019
3    Fri,  12   Apr   2019
4    Mon,  13   May   2019
5    Wed,  08   May   2019  
6    Fri,  10   May   2019.........
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[RFC 5545, section 3.3.10.](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545#section-3.3.10) states:

> Each BYDAY value can also be preceded by a positive (+n) or
> negative (-n) integer.  If present, this indicates the nth
> occurrence of a specific day within the MONTHLY or YEARLY "RRULE".

So the rule you're looking for literally specifies the 2nd Monday (`2MO`), Wednesday (`2WE`) and Friday (`2FR`) of each month.

[`FREQ=MONTHLY;COUNT=10;BYDAY=2MO,2WE,2FR`](http://recurrence-expansion-service.appspot.com/reaas?dtstart=20190408&rrule=FREQ%3DMONTHLY%3BCOUNT%3D10%3BBYDAY%3D2MO%2C2WE%2C2FR&skip=&max_instances=100&expansion_window_end=21000101)
(click to see the results)

Note that `INTERVAL=1` is the default and `WKST=SU` is meaningless in this case, so you can just as well omit them.

Btw, your rule basically says, of all Mondays, Wednesdays and Fridays of a month, take the second instance in that month.